# Allow camera and microphone settings programatically

Tags: c#, java, flash

Flash player has an option in Flash Player Settings manager> camera and Mic > camera and microphone settings > camera and microphone settings by site >

when clicks on this button it shows "website" and "camera and Mic access " we can manually add a website and access permission here.

Is it possible to do programmatic?

If so how...?

I prefer to get a code in C# or Java

Comment: I sure hope it's not possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all, I have achieved it by editing sol file. even though it was a tedious task as no documentation available, achieved it with reading each character in the sol file and adding my site content to it.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail on how you achieved this?

Comment: i think user needs to first always allow the flash content to access the microphone and camera right? If you could actually provide how you achieved it. It would be more helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I have achieved it 2 year back and didn't worked on it much. But client uses it now also. I will try to recollect the steps I done for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

Access to the microphone is done through a permissions-based system in Flash itself.  Similar to Google, Facebook & LinkedIn etc., it's done on a approval-from-user basis.

[Please read the flash documentation for more information](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help03.html).

Comment: I saw a lot of entries in my flash player settings all with askme previledge, How it automatically added to my settings..? If possible how can i add code for this in my app.?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're meaning there.  There's pleanty of documentation on how to access the microphone & camera and I don't have code to show you sorry.

If you're meaning to automatically do this & skip showing it to the user, you're not able to do that.  Kind of defeats the purpose of asking them in the first place :)

Comment: Also, if you feel this solution is solved, mark it as so and we can add additional comments if necessary here.

Comment: Is there any way to do it for the client computer from a program that's installed on the client computer?